# Rails 4 - Create record with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my project i have something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :roles
  has_many  :websites, through: :roles
end

class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates                 :name, presence: true
  has_many                  :roles
  has_many                  :users, through: :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :website
end
```

So when I try to do:

```
User.first.websites.create(name: "First")
```

I have this error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank
```

How can i create a new User Website in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation error is actually coming from the Role model, which also has validation for the name attribute.

You can do it in one line by creating the website through the role, using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :website

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :website
end

User.first.roles.create(name: "Role name", website_attributes: { name: "Website name" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove `validates :name, presence: true` from `role` model then it will work.